# JS: Filter array only for non-empty and type of string values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array like this:

```
array.filter(e => { return e })
```

With this I want to filter all empty strings including `undefined` and `null`.
Unfortunately my array have some arrays, which should not be there. So I need also to check only for string values and remove all other.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the type of the elements using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
array.filter(e => typeof e === 'string' && e !== '')
```

Since `''` is falsy, you could simplify by just testing if `e` was truthy, though the above is more explicit

```
array.filter(e => typeof e === 'string' && e)
```

```js
const array = [null, undefined, '', 'hello', '', 'world', 7, ['some', 'array'], null]

console.log(
  array.filter(e => typeof e === 'string' && e !== '')
)
```

Comment: This works too, but keep in mind that `typeof e === 'string' && e` could return a string and not always a boolean as requested by filter callback definition.

Comment: @cyrix, the callback filters by values [that coerce to true (truthy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Description). I prefer to be implicit, it was just provided for comparison

Answer (score 4):

You could check for a string and empty both in your filter method:

```
array.filter(e => (typeof e === 'string') && !!e)
```

Note: `!!e` returns `false` if the element is `null`, `undefined`, `''` or 0.

I should mention that the "arrow"-function syntax only works in browsers that support ES6 or higher.

The alternative is:

```
array.filter(function(e) {
    return (typeof e === 'string') && !!e;
});
```

Note: Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.filter` doesn't exist in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
const justStrings = array.filter(element => 
    (typeof element === 'string' || element instanceof String)
    && element
)
```

### Explanation

To be shure your element is a `string` you have to check that it isn't a *variable type* (`let str = 'hello'`) or an *instance of String* (`new String('hello')`) because this case would return `object` by `typeof element`.

Additionally you have to check if your element exists.

Answer (score 0):

When returning a method that consists of one line as a callback in es6 there is no need for `return` as this happens implicitly.

Hope this helps :-)

```js
let arr = ["", "", "fdsff", [], null, {}, undefined];

let filteredArr = arr.filter(item => (typeof item === "string" && !item) || !item)
                  
console.log(filteredArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to filter by instance of / type of

> arr.filter((item) => item instanceof String);